# JSF core tag <c:forEach/> value overflow while iterate

Tags: jsf, types, jstl, overflow, iteration

I have problem with core tag  in JSF. Im using this tag for pagination button rendering. There is one big problem - when there is more then 127pages. Iteration value overflows. It looks like the iteration value is BYTE typed :-(. There is a code:

```
<c:forEach begin="#{listActionBean.start}" step="#{listActionBean.step}" end="#{listActionBean.allCnt}" var="i">
      <ice:outputText value="#{i}"/>
      <ice:outputText value="|"/>
    </c:forEach>
```

Values on the listActionBean are INT typed. Its the same when i write:

```
<c:forEach begin="1" step="1" end="150" var="i">
      <ice:outputText value="#{i}"/>
      <ice:outputText value="|"/>
    </c:forEach>
```

The output is:

1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 | 25 | 26 | 27 | 28 | 29 | 30 | 31 | 32 | 33 | 34 | 35 | 36 | 37 | 38 | 39 | 40 | 41 | 42 | 43 | 44 | 45 | 46 | 47 | 48 | 49 | 50 | 51 | 52 | 53 | 54 | 55 | 56 | 57 | 58 | 59 | 60 | 61 | 62 | 63 | 64 | 65 | 66 | 67 | 68 | 69 | 70 | 71 | 72 | 73 | 74 | 75 | 76 | 77 | 78 | 79 | 80 | 81 | 82 | 83 | 84 | 85 | 86 | 87 | 88 | 89 | 90 | 91 | 92 | 93 | 94 | 95 | 96 | 97 | 98 | 99 | 100 | 101 | 102 | 103 | 104 | 105 | 106 | 107 | 108 | 109 | 110 | 111 | 112 | 113 | 114 | 115 | 116 | 117 | 118 | 119 | 120 | 121 | 122 | 123 | 124 | 125 | 126 | 127 | -128 | -127 | -126 | -125 | -124 | -123 | -122 | -121 | -120 | -119 | -118 | -117 | -116 | -115 | -114 | -113 | -112 | -111 | -110 | -109 | -108 | -107 | -106 |

You can se the negative numbers. Is there some kind of switch to "longer" data type? or some another solution? Thank you for reply.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It works if you use `varStatus` instead of `var`:

```
<c:forEach begin="1" step="1" end="150" varStatus="status">
    <h:outputText value="#{status.index}" />
    <h:outputText value="|" />
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: hmm... I never have expected that. But thanx.

Comment: Is there any reasonable explanation for such behaviour?